# Insight API: txs json shows only 10 tx?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcore

I have an Insight API Server running, it's fully synced and working. I would like to get a json to receive every tx within a block.

On https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api it says I have to use:

```
Transactions by Block
  /insight-api/txs/?block=HASH
  /insight-api/txs/?block=00000000fa6cf7367e50ad14eb0ca4737131f256fc4c5841fd3c3f140140e6b6
```

For example we take block #301453. This block has 725 transactions.

https://insight.bitpay.com/block/00000000000000004dff81aadf782cceb8a2d082f0f255472791c8bb2984e958

If I use the api to get the json file with this link:

```
http://localhost:3001/insight-api/txs/?block=00000000000000004dff81aadf782cceb8a2d082f0f255472791c8bb2984e958
```

... then it shows the first 10 transactions only (numbers 0 - 9). **But there are 725 tx in this block.**

It looks like the number 10 are those addresses are the first who are displayed. If i scroll further down, more transactions appear. But why does the json request only show 10 txs?

How can I get ALL transactions in this block - as the documentations mentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1:**
The returned json includes a "pageTotal":'some number'.
You can create a for-loop to loop through all the pages with API calls.

Let assume there are two pages aka "pageTotal":2

To fetch the first page, append parameter [&pageNum=0] to the end
**Example usage:**

```
http://localhost:3001/insight-api/txs/?block=00000000000000004dff81aadf782cceb8a2d082f0f255472791c8bb2984e958&pageNum=0
```

To fetch the second page, add param [&pageNum=1]
**Example usage:**

```
http://localhost:3001/insight-api/txs/?block=00000000000000004dff81aadf782cceb8a2d082f0f255472791c8bb2984e958&pageNum=1
```

**Option 2:**
Modify [transactions.js](https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api/blob/master/lib/transactions.js) , 'var pageLength' on Line 253.
The default is 'var pageLength = 10;'
Unsure if there are consequences by doing this, but I assume it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I changed "var pageLength" to 50000. This should list 50.000 tx and should last a while. :) I think option two is the faster solution.